# Angular JS & Semantic-UI checkbox needs double click

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, semantic-ui

I try to operate with AngularJS on checkbox made with Semantic UI:

```
<div class="ui checkbox" ng-click="myCtrl.value=!myCtrl.value">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" ng-model="myCtrl.value"/>
<label>Property</label>
</div>
```

It looks, like any copy of my Semantic-ui checkbox needs to be "activated" by a click. First click is changing the value, but not the appearance. Then my Semantic-ui checkbox is always one step behind - it shows the opposite state to the one saved under "value" variable.

I noticed, that as I use "normal" checkbox, clicking on the label works fine, but clicking on the input change it's state twice (returns to the first state):

```
<div ng-click="myCtrl.value=!myCtrl.value">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCtrl.value"/> Property</label>
</div>
```

This is probably something really basic, but as I am working on my first Angular project ever, really basic things are still really big problems:) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the `hidden` class on the input

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div class="ui checkbox" ng-click="myCtrl.value=!myCtrl.value">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCtrl.value" />
      <label>Property</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantic's JS often doesn't play nicely with Angular.

You may need to set the checkbox's appearance explicitly in the controller.

```
<div class="ui checkbox" ng-click="setValue()">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" ng-model="myCtrl.value"/>
  <label>Property</label>
</div>
```

And then in your controller:

```
myCtrl.setValue = function() {
  myCtrl.value = !myCtrl.value; // sets value
  $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox(myCtrl.value ? 'check' : 'uncheck'); // updates checkbox appearance to match
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - still needs that special "magic click" to activate. Gived up - will try to just use styles from Semantic JS and operate on checkboxes with Angular.